# iOS 8 imageView inside scrollView with autolayout not working

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, ios8, autolayout

This is a very simple `ViewController`. I have an `imageView` inside a `scrollView`. Using autolayout I set `scrollview`'s constraints to its `view`'s edges. Also, `imageView` mode is `AspectFit`.

[image]

The image is provided at runtime, and it may be a landscape or portrait size. When I run the app, the image doesn't fit the current screen size. It seems that `scrollView`'s boundaries are not being honored, thus only part of the image is being displayed. It used to work on ios7 and xcode5, but it's broken for ios8 xcode6.

[image]

Any ideas? I need to keep the use of autolayout whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to set the imageviews horizontal constraints and pin them to self.view (the scrollviews parent view) instead of the scrollview.

There is a good example of this here:
[Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)

Comment: Thanks... I'll be trying this solution. Seems that may get the job done. Let you know soon

Comment: Hey I had the similar problem, I have put constraint on both side, it's working for the left, but not for the right side, make sure to post here if you find the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this to zoom out completely

```
[self.scrollView zoomToRect:self.imageView.frame animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a call to imageView.sizeToFit() in viewDidLoad? My impression is that imageView's size is fluid until the outlets are set. A call to sizeToFit forces the issue.